# Resource management in decoupled applications

Tags: .net, database, mvvm, prism

I'm building decoupled application using Unity, Prism.
 
The problem I worry about is resource management in services. Easier to explain in example: 
Imagine w have some interface IDataRetriever which provides us with some sort of data. Implementation is registered as an instance.
Implementation of this interface could be based on anything: Files (FileDataRetriever), Sql Server (SqlServerDataRetriever), even simple Dictionary. Concrete implementation to use is configured (possibly via configuration file, but it doesn't matter). 
  Once application finished working, depending on service implementation it should sometimes release resources (e.g. close connections, close files etc) or not (e.g. when using Dictionary), but as I work with decoupled abstractions I don't know both things:
1. When the resources should be released
2. Whether concrete implementation needs resource deallocation or not.

I could think of scenario when bootstrapper would implement IDisposable, and check each service for IDisposable implementation, and also call Dispose for all modules (which would mean that all modules would have to implement IDisposable as well) but it just doesn't look like correct way of handling such things (too complex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may decide that you're able (and in fact it's preferable) to release the resources as soon as your data retriever has finished its operation. In this case, the releasing of resources will be implicit in the call to your `GetData` or equivalent method that is part of the abstraction that your client code uses.

Alternatively, if you don't wish to release resources until some point until after you've retrieved your data, then you will need to expose a `Release` or equivalent method on your abstraction. It is messy forcing services to implement this method if they don't require it, so you could place this method on a separate interface, and only implement it for the appropriate services.

You client code could then check that the injected service implements this interface at the appropriate time, and invoke the `Release` method if appropriate.

Comment: Releasing resources after each operation is not really possible.
Implementing interface with Release method, I believe is the same as implementing IDisposable that I've described in the initial post. I currently think about Finalizers, doesn't it look like right place to use them?

Comment: You shouldn't call Dispose or Close in a finalizer, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. It doesn't seem that finalizers are appropriate here. You could use IDisposable yes, just on the types that require it, and test for it in your client.